# How to obtain Twitter access token and secret on iOs?

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth, authorization, token

What I've got:
1. RoR back end
2. iOs 6 app 
3. Twitter ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret that back end uses

What I whant:
Add a Twitter sign in button to my iOs app that would allow me to authorize user and get his AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret to use in my back end part. I've been searching all over the web for a up to date working solution for almost a week but didn't found anything.

Facebook took almost 5 minutes to create a WebView and put there they oAuth url which gives token right into address bar after user authorization. Why the hell is Twitter is such an ass pain??

Help!! ><

Answer (score 6):

You need to use Reverse Auth to get the oAuth access token and access token secret as described in this [tutorial](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth).

You can find a working example [here](https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample) from Sean Cook, engineer at Twitter.

Comment: "You were not granted access to the Twitter accounts."

AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret are right.

Comment: If you or your users decide not to give you access to their Twitter accounts, there is not much you can do, except maybe show an alert explaining why Twitter login is important and how they can re-enable it by changing the switch in the System Preferences -> Privacy -> Twitter -> <Your app name>

Comment: Oh. Now I see what this example is doing. It's getting account saved in my phone settings and tries to authorize on a single buttons press.

Don't need this. I want to let user input his login and pass right in the app.

Comment: Example from [Sean Cook](https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample) worked for me. (iOS 6,7,8). Thanks [andreagiavatto](http://stackoverflow.com/users/806617/andreagiavatto)